# DocBook5 <step> not allowed in <sidebar>? (can't render PDF with xsltproc+fop)

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop, docbook-5

I have a DocBook5 doc which renders into chunked HTML using xsltproc just fine.

I am now trying to render to PDF, but at the fo output stage, xsltproc gives me:

```
Element step in namespace 'http://docbook.org/ns/docbook' encountered in sidebar, but no template matches.
```

If I try to render the resulting fo using fop, indeed, xsltproc seems to have left out the steps in any procedures in sidebars, because fop chokes on the first one:

```
...pdf/book.fo:9:1597: Error(9/1597): fo:list-block is missing child elements.
Required Content Model: marker* (list-item)+
```

How come xsltproc doesn't care about this when it comes to chunked HTML, but doesn't like this for fo?

Update: Seems it's the stylesheet that makes this message:

```
$ cat /usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-ns-stylesheets-1.75.2/fo/docbook.xsl | grep -B 15 "but no template matches"
<xsl:key name="id" match="*" use="@id|@xml:id"/>

<!-- ==================================================================== -->

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:message>
    <xsl:text>Element </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
    <xsl:text> in namespace '</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>' encountered</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="parent::*">
      <xsl:text> in </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name(parent::*)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>, but no template matches.</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Is "Element step in namespace 'http://docbook.org/ns/docbook' encountered in sidebar ..." a message the stylesheet outputs using `xsl:message` or is that a message the XSLT processor generates on its own?

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for the lead, I've updated the question.  (Stylesheet.)

Comment: According to http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/AddNewTemplate.html#AddProcessingSteps, the message is output when the stylesheet processes an element not defined in the docbook format. Are you sure a `step` belongs in there? If that is a custom element then as far as I understand it you need to provide a template to handle it.

Comment: It seems to be a defined element http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/step.html but it parent has to be one of `procedure, stepalternatives, substeps`, not `sidebar`. So maybe someone familiar with docbook can tell you how to properly markup a `step` if you show how you currently use it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, All my `step`s are within `procedure`s, including the ones within `sidebar`s.  Although, I also have some plain `sidebar`s within `step`s.  However, none of this causes a problem in HTML, and looks fine when rendered that way.

Comment: Is it possible the template just doesn't know how to render it when it comes to PDF?

Comment: I don't see why that template would output the parent's name as `sidebar` if in your XML input it is a `procedure`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen that's a good point.  I did search all my sidebars for steps though.  It's too bad they don't output the filename and line number with these things.

Comment: Although, the fact that fop complains that there's a list block container without elements would seem to indicate that the template is somehow mistaken, because the fo contains a `procedure` without `step`s in it.